# Why wouldn't the diode in this transistor scheme turn on?

Tags: diodes

[image]

In the schematic above, the diode should not light, but why? (Ignore the pencil drawings on the schematic).

Comment: What makes you believe it should? There's obviously homework here, but what have you tried?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to eesx. Can you please explain where you are stuck? If you show some effort and some understanding of the topic, you will get help much more easily!

Comment: It's a NPN transistor.  If the emitter is at 0V, how do you forward bias the PN BE junction?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The transistor is off since it's base-emitter junction is reverse-biased.  That allows no current to flow thru the collector, which keeps the LED off.

The B-E junction looks like a diode to the external circuit.  The special thing that a BJT (bipolar junction transistor) does is allow C-E current some multiple of the B-E current.  That multiple is the gain.

Since you have the B-E "diode" reverse biased, no current flow thru it.  That, in turn, does not allow for any collector current.

Being a silicon diode, the B-E junction drops about 600-750 mV when conducting useful current.  Depending on the value of the base resistor, you could start to see the LED come on with the input being about 1 V or more.

Let's work thru some numbers to pick good values for the resistors.  Let's say this is a common green LED rated for 20 mA, and that it drops 2.1 when fully on.  The C-E drop of the transistor in saturation is about 200 mV.  After the LED and the C-E drop, that leaves 6.7 V across the LED resistor.

We want 20 mA to flow, so use Ohm's law:  (6.7 V)/(20 mA) = 335 Ω, which is the minimum resistance to not over-drive the LED.  I'd round that up to at least the next common value of 360 Ω to give some margin.  Working backwards, the LED current would be 18.6 mA.  You wouldn't notice the difference in brightness between that and 20 mA, even in a side by side comparison.

Let's require the transistor to have at least a gain of 30, which is very easy to find in a small signal NPN.  You want 20 mA collector current, so you need at least (20 mA)/30 = 670 µA base current.

Let's assume you want to drive this LED from a typical digital output that is either 0 V for off and 3.3 V for on.  Figure the B-E junction will drop 700 mV, so that leaves 2.6 V across the base resistor.  Again using Ohm's law, the base resistor needs to be no more than 3.9 kΩ.  Round down to the next common value of 3.6 kΩ.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering Can you clarify which part is the emitter and which is the collector? Also is this a PNP or NPN transistor?

Comment: @Ali: That's *really basic* knowledge we expect people to have before coming here. Surely there are many references available that even a modicum of searching would uncover, so no point cluttering up this site to repeat them here.  However, briefly, you show a NPN.  Go look up the rest.

Comment: Two downvotes now? I'm really mystified what someone thinks is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The transistor is working in cut off region here.  So no current is flowing in the collector circuit.

Answer (score 0):

A mental model for the semantics of an (NPN) BJT is an ideal current source from the collector to the emitter,  where the actual current is some gain times the current from the base to the emitter.  You see inside the BJT a diode between the base and emitter and you should [immediately think "diode drop"](https://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~dsculley/tutorial/diodes/diodes1.html): as long as the voltage bias from base to emitter is over the drop voltage, a lot of current can flow.  To actually get the gain and drop you would consult the manufacturer's data sheets for your BJT in question.

Your diode is reverse-biased causing no current to flow from base to emitter, and therefore the current source is set to 0.

Comment: UM... really? you have so many things backward here. Though the last sentence is right.

Comment: *"gain times the current from the base to the collector"*.  No.  The possible collector current is the B-E current times the gain.

Comment: ..I meant the last sentence is almost right... sigh

Comment: @Trevor: Yes, this whole answer needs to be seriously fixed or just deleted.  I usually don't downvote other answers to questions I also answered, but in this case I made a exception.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Hopefully that's better: I think you are both objecting about me getting the labels wrong about which terminal is emitter and which is collector, rather than actually upset about the mental model offered. I am somewhat interested in your use of the term "possible" though. Are you just pointing out that a given BJT is not always ideal? Or is this current-source thinking wrong even in some ideal regime? (I ask because I thought I knew of a current source implementation based on a BJT and a reverse biased Zener: but I would like to know if that was a lie.)

Comment: I said "possible" because the base current times the gain only sets what the collector current can be.  If the collector is left open, for example, then it's current is 0 regardless of the base current and the gain.

Answer (score 0):

No current will flow since the transistor is "closed", because Vbe = -2V and it should be at least positive and to be fully open above ~0.7V.